# MongoDB - find item in list and return distinct documents

Tags: mongodb

Suppose I have a collection of documents in a MongoDB. Does there exist a query to see if a string is in a value's list, and if so, return only distinct documents based on a particular key's value?

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5504d11b6946aa2b4dff7e99"),
    "states" : [ 
        "AL", 
        "AZ", 
        "TX"
    ],
    "name" : "Foo",
    "rating" : "NR",
    "url" : "www.domain.com",
};

   {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5504d11b6946aa2b4dff7e98"),
        "states" : [ 
            "AL", 
            "NJ", 
            "NY"
        ],
        "name" : "Bar",
        "rating" : "NR",
        "url" : "www.domain.com",
    };

  {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5504d11b6946aa2b4dff7e97"),
        "states" : [ 
            "AL", 
            "AZ", 
            "TX"
        ],
        "name" : "The Grinch",
        "rating" : "NR",
        "url" : "www.domain.net",
    }
```

For example, 
If `AL` is in `states`, return only the collections where the URL is distinct -
would return the first, and last collection in the above examples.

`db.collections.find({"states":{'$in':["AL"]}})`

is what I am using to find the state in the list.

`db.collections.aggregate({ $group: { _id: '$url', n: { $max: '$states' } } })`.

result is what I am using to get distinct collections based on the domain.

Where I'm running into trouble is combining the two in a single statement.

Answer (score 0):

It'd look like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$match: {$states: 'AL'}},
    {$group:{_id: '$url'}}
]);
```

`$max` and `$in` are unnecessary expenses in your call.

Comment: uncaught exception: aggregate failed: {
 "errmsg" : "exception: bad query: BadValue unknown top level operator: $states",
 "code" : 16810,
 "ok" : 0
}

Comment: this works, however the other key:value pairs are missing from results: `db.carriers.aggregate([
    {$match: {"states":{'$in':["AL"]}}},
    {$group:{_id: '$url'}}
]).result`